# Agent based modeling in anylogic

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I need a help :( 
I am new in anylogic, the problem is i have 4 identical machines  each machine has 5 different critical parts. 
I want these critical parts to represent one machine. What i tried to do is i create a machine agent type with population 4, and Inside the diagram of the machine agent I created 5 critical part agent type( i.e cp1 ,cp2..cp5) each with initial no. Of agent = 1, and i extended those cps to the machine agent type..is this correct? I am confused because i have 4 machines, does the initial no of CP should be 4 to be distributed to the 4 machines? 
I know it is very stupid question :) 
Thank you

Comment: What is the role of the critical parts? How will them be used?
Please provide more detail and structure your thoughts.

Comment: It is a chiller machine consists of 5 CP like condenser, evaporator, compressor sensor and valves. They are critical because the chiller cannot function without them.  What i want to do is to have spare part inventory for each CP, so if one CP fails i can send a spare part for it. That is why I need to create them inside the machine.

Answer (score 1):

If this behavior will only occur in the case of a failure you can model this in a different way. Incorporate fails in the resourcePool and select the flowchart option (instead of modeling it with a delay). In that flowchart you have a pickup (or a similar action) from a queue that should contain the spare parts. Tweaking this behavior will probably be a better approach than modeling the 5 critical parts and use them all.

I would suggest the following approach. 
Create a resource pool for each part and require its use in the service(see image):

[image][image]

Then, for each of the resource Pools, you will model failures, as in the picture, and the repair task is a flowchart.

[image][image]

You will need to have a queue to represent the spare parts storage. From there you can remove the specific part you want (this will require you to model that information into the agent type and then search the queue but I expect you to know how to do that.

[image]

The repair task is very simple in my example but you can and should improve it to your needs.

Hope this is enough for you to solve your problem.

Best regards, 
Luís

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful

Comment: If this answers your problem, just define that in the answer for this topic to be closed ;)